# Send Anonymous Object to Service Bus Queue in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I have a method in c# that takes a set of properties wrapped in a class and push it to azure service bus queue. There are so many types that need to be pushed so I wrote a method that takes anonymous object and just use the BrokeredMessaging class to send it to the service bus queue.

Something along this line:

```
//I intially used the string type to know what type of class is passed 
//and then using switch statement, handle each case accordingly.
//But it becomes a very long list of switch statements and I don't want that.
public static bool QueueUp(Object obj, string type)
{
    var msg = new BrokeredMessage(obj);
    _sendObjClient.Send(msg);
}
```

This code isn't working. I'd like to save the many places where this method is called from passing in explicitly typed object; they should just send any object and I want this portion of the code to do the hard work and send it serialized to the queue.

Just got introduced to `System.Reflection` namespace but I'm yet to grab how to actually achieve my goal.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably doing something wrong. It should work with any type and should serialize types automatically from an `object`. The type should have some attributes to allow the serializer to pick up internal state that needs to be serialized. Can you explain more: *"This code isn't working."*?

Comment: Okay. It threw an exception. Let me rerun it and I'll pick the type of exception it threw.

Comment: It threw a `System.InvalidOperationException` exception.

Comment: Add more details, like `Message` and `StackTrace`, by looking at those you can figure out what is going wrong

Comment: Oh thanks. I just tried running my worker role now and checking the queue count in azure and it does appear to be working, The message is sent and the worker role did consumed it. Upon stepping into the code, however, I noticed the `System.InvalidOperationException` upon inspection is still there. Quiet funny but I wondered what went wrong in the first place.

Comment: By the way I'm using the April 2013 release of the Azure SDK. Could that have been an issue? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mark the class and properties of your object as serializable - from [How to Use Service Bus Queues](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-queues/):

> Messages sent to (and received from) Service Bus queues are instances
>   of the BrokeredMessage class. BrokeredMessage objects have a set of
>   standard properties (such as Label and TimeToLive), a dictionary that
>   is used to hold custom application specific properties, and a body of
>   arbitrary application data. An application can set the body of the
>   message by passing any serializable object into the constructor of the
>   BrokeredMessage, and the appropriate DataContractSerializer will then
>   be used to serialize the object. Alternatively, a System.IO.Stream can
>   be provided.

Then review [SerializableAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) to learn how to mark your class as Serializable.

Comment: The code is working fine now. Though, if I debug and inspect the `msg` object, I still see `System.InvalidOperationException`. Don't know why. I'm using the latest version of Azure SDK.